# How can I put my exception information into an IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#

I am using the following code to get exceptions from my MVC Model State:

```
        IEnumerable<string> exceptions = ModelState (x => x.Value.Errors
                .Where(error => (error != null) &&
                                (error.Exception != null) &&
                                (error.Exception.Message != null))
                .Select(error => error.Exception.Message));
```

For try-catch block exceptions **how could I code a way to take the exception e and make it so my exception and inner exception messages were also put into an IEnumerable** like I am doing above?

My problem is that I am not sure how to handle the fact that there could be multiple levels of exceptions.

Not sure if this helps but here's the code I was using before to put exceptions into a string:

```
    public static string GetFormattedErrorMessage(this Exception e)
    {
        var exError = "";
        if ( 1 == 1) {
            if (e == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("e");
            }

            exError = e.Message;
            if (e.InnerException != null)
            {
                exError += "<br>" + e.InnerException.Message;
                exError += "<br>" + e.StackTrace;
                if (e.InnerException.InnerException != null)
                {
                    exError += "<br>" + e.InnerException.InnerException.Message;
                }
            }
        } else {
            exError = "System error";
        }
        return exError;
    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `if ( 1 == 1)`?

Comment: a) Why do you want to expose exceptions? b) What's wrong with `Exception.ToString()`? It automatically includes all information from the inner exceptions.  `yourException.ToString().Replace("\r\n", "<br>");`

Comment: @jgauffin the OP might not want all the stack trace info.

Comment: @James: Well. The code in the question just duplicates the one generated by ToString()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could traverse down the inner exceptions e.g.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetErrors(Exception ex)
{
    ...

    var results = new List<string>() { ex.Message };
    var innerEx = ex.InnerException;
    while (innerEx != null) 
    {
        results.Add(innerEx.Message);
        innerEx = innerEx.InnerException;
    }
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a problem for a recursive method. See if the following can get you started. I'll leave it up to you to include the StackTrace and handle AggregateExceptions:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> FormatExceptionHtml(Exception instance)
{
    if (instance != null)
        yield return instance.Message + "<br />";
    if (instance.InnerException != null)
        foreach (var inner in FormatExceptionHtml(instance.InnerException))
        {
            yield return inner;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the only "interesting" bit is enumerating over the inner exceptions. No need to manually build the data structures; a simple enumerator should drastically simplify the problem:

```
public static IEnumerable<Exception> AsEnumerable(this Exception self)
{
    for (var e = self; e != null; e = e.InnerException) yield return e;
}

foreach (var e in myException.AsEnumerable()) { /* print debug info */ }

// or
var exceptionString = string.Join("<br>", myException.AsEnumerable().Select(e =>
    /* debug info */
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use recursion to get every level of exception :

```
private static string GetFormattedErrorMessage(this Exception ex)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (ex != null)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(ex.Message);
        sb.AppendLine(ex.StackTrace);
        sb.AppendLine(ex.InnerException.GetFormattedErrorMessage());
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Or use plain

```
ex.ToString();
```

Which will print out quite nicely.

Comment: Or a loop as @James's answer.

Comment: Probably better to pass the string builder through, otherwise you're not really getting the benefit of it.

Comment: @MattDavey Yes, but in the end, the iterative version performs better so it should be used instead (with a stringbuilder or an enumeration).